# How to unistalled Go tools in Linux using command line?

Tags: apt, package-management, golang

I installed `cf` using

```
go get github.com/xalanq/cf-tool
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/xalanq/cf-tool
go build -ldflags "-s -w" cf.go

cf --version
output: Codeforces Tool (cf) v1.0.0
```

I tried to uninstall it using

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove Codeforces\ Tool && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove cf && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

but iam getting error like

```
E: Unable to locate package Codeforces Tool
```

and

```
E: Unable to locate package cf
```

but its' showing error how to unistall this

Answer (score 4):

You may only uninstall software with `apt` that you have installed with `apt`.  If you have installed software using other ways, `apt` will not be able to uninstall that software and you would have to use other ways of removing it from your system.

For example, the Go software infrastructure and `apt` are separate, and binaries and other files installed via `go get` or `go install` are not recognised by `apt` in any way.

To delete the `cf-tool` project from `$GOPATH`, you may try

```bash
go clean -x -i
```

from the module directory, `$GOPATH/src/github.com/xalanq/cf-tool`.  This is how you usually uninstall a piece of Go software you have built and installed from a project's source directory with `go install`.
However, you seem to be running a slightly outdated version of the Go language tools, so I don't know whether that works (see `go help clean`).

Removing the files with `rm` would also work (using the pathnames that you mention in your question):

```bash
rm -r "$GOPATH/src/github.com/xalanq/cf-tool"
rm "$GOPATH/bin/cf"
```

However, on my system with Go version `go1.21.0` (which means I would use `go install` rather than `go get` to install the `cf` thing)
the paths and filenames are *quite* different:

```bash
rm -r "${GOPATH:-$HOME/go}/pkg/mod/github.com/xalanq/cf-tool@v1.0.0"
rm "${GOPATH:-$HOME/go}/bin/cf-tool"
```

In short: Use `rm` to delete the executable and the module directory.

Comment: It will delete all files and data related to that software or I need to clear it separately?

Comment: @MdNihal05 If you have used the software to create files, you would have to remove those files separately.

Answer (score 1):

The command name might be just `cf` for easy typing, but the name of the software package might be longer. Or the tool might not be installed from a `*.deb` package at all.

Run `dpkg-query -S $(which cf)` to try and find out the actual package name first. If there is no output, then the `cf` tool was not installed using a package manager. [It appears to be delivered by the developer as a single executable](https://github.com/xalanq/cf-tool/releases) that is just dropped into some directory in $PATH; if that's how you installed it, then just delete it to uninstall it.

Comment: ```dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local/bin/cf```  should i do ```sudo rm- rf /usr/local/bin/cf```

Comment: The management of `/usr/local/bin/` directory is completely the responsibility of the local system administrator/owner. So unless *you* know you use some tool to manage your `/usr/local/bin`, you can just use `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/cf`. No need for the `-rf` option, because this is just a single file. Using `rm -rf` when there is no need for it risks great destruction if you make a typo.